# Laravel Search by 3 values get nothing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a bunch of columns in a table what I need is to filter the table using few parameters using laravel Eloquent ORM.

For example companyName, StartDate. what I have tried is below

```
$objFetch = OpenOrder::where('companyName', $request->majorCompanies)
    ->orwhereBetween(
        'StartDate',
        array($request->startDate_start, $request->startDate_end)
    )
    ->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'objects' => $objFetch
]);


  "objects": [
                {
                   "company": "aa",
                   "StartDate": 2/24/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "aa"
                   "StartDate": 2/25/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "aa",
                   "StartDate": 4/15/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "bb",
                   "StartDate": 4/18/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "bb",
                   "StartDate": 2/24/2021,
                },
    
            ]
```

the answer should output the information given by the user for example:
if the user select company `aa` and date between `2/24/2021`,`2/30/2021` output should be

```
"objects": [
                {
                   "company": "aa",
                   "StartDate": 2/24/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "aa"
                   "StartDate": 2/25/2021,
                },
                {
                   "company": "bb",
                   "StartDate": 2/24/2021,
                },
    
            ]
```

write your answers to solve this issue

Comment: You're using `or`, which means `where company is aa OR start_date is between some values`. Your output is 100% correct for the code you have written. If you want to limit it, you need to use `and` (i.e. `->where(...)->whereBetween(...)` instead of `->where(...)->orWhereBetween(...)`).

Comment: `->where(...)->whereBetween(...)` returns nothing

Comment: What is the data type of `$request->majorCompanies`?

Comment: You'll have to debug that further then. Try to get the raw query working in a SQL editor and compare it to the generated SQL from this query (you can use `DB::enableQueryLog()` then `DB::getQueryLog()` to see the raw SQL). Also, replace `...` with `'companyName', $request->majorCompanies` and `'StartDate', array($request->startDate_start, $request->startDate_end)`, those were placeholders (I assume you didn't use `...`, but figured I'd add that in case you took that code as non-pseudo code)

Comment: both columns are string @Milad

Comment: You're storing your dates as strings? Well that'll be a problem for `whereBetween()` ...

Comment: is that possible to filter with string value @TimLewis

Comment: Replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and output `$objFetch` to see the raw SQL query as a string. Then post it here please.

Comment: Not easily; you'd have to perform some raw SQL manipulation to parse/cast those to dates before you did `between`. Are you able to update `StartDate` to a `date`-type column? It'll work natively if you do that.

Comment: `{"success":true,"objects":"select * from `open_orders` where (`companyName` = ? and `StartDate` = ?) order by `id` desc"}` this is the output i get @Milad

Comment: @TimLewis I tried by changing the type to date. it stores the recode as 00000 because I directly import from an excel sheet and store

Comment: I Solved the issue guys. Thank you for your suggestion. i solved it by storing the started time as Unix timestamp and filtered by dateBetween